# Xen and traffic shaping

Tags: xen, tc, traffic

I want to limit the incoming and outgoing traffic for a guest machine on a Xen Host.
There is a total of `1000Mbit/s` available on the host.

The guest machine has its own interface, let's say `vif1.0`

So it goes trough `vif1.0 -> peth1 (bridge) -> eth0 (host)`

Here is my code:

```
# Remove possibly existing Rules
tc qdisc del dev vif1.0 root
# Add Qdisc
tc qdisc add dev vif1.0 root handle 1: cbq avpkt 1000 bandwidth 1000mbit
# Add Class
tc class add dev vif1.0 parent 1: classid 1:1 cbq rate 40mbit allot 1500 prio 5 bounded isolated
# Add Filter for incoming traffic
tc filter add dev vif1.0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 16 u32 match ip dst x.x.x.x flowid 1:1
# Add Filter for outgoing traffic
tc filter add dev vif1.0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 16 u32 match ip src x.x.x.x flowid 1:1
```

This solution works for shaping the incoming traffic.
But the outgoing traffic is still using the whole 1000Mbit/s

Do I have to create the rules on `peth1`?